# Max sum non adjacent and k size subsequence

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

You are given a number n, representing the count of elements.
2. You are given n numbers, representing n elements.
3. You are given an integer k.
3. You are required to find the maximum sum of a subsequence having at most k elements. 
4. Adjacent elements can't be selected.
*You have to solve it using Dynamic Programming (preferred - tabulation).
Input Format

A number n
n1
n2
.. n number of elements
A number k
Constraints

1 <= n <= 1000
1 <= k <= 500
-1000 <= n1, n2, .. n elements <= 1000
Output Format

A number.
Sample Input 0

9
4 1 2 5 8 3 1 9 7
3
Sample Output 0

21

Answer (score 0):

-First, it seems u mean ur elements <=1000 not the reverse (no need for the "1000<=" in the start of the line before the sample i/p & o/p)

-Then, it is not necessary to use dynamic programming. This is even a simpler version of this Q
[How to find optimal partition subsets](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/125521/how-to-find-optimal-partition-subsets)

-Simply search for the $ n[max] $ value, repeat in a loop $K-1$ times

$DO$  Find n[max2]    $WHILE$ |max2-max1|>1

This is just a pseudo code, if u must to, u can change it to a recursive dynamic programming form. Something like

SOL(n, k) =..... + SOL(n-1,k-1)

I hope this is clear enough